# Generic List.Join

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an object

```
public class Title
    {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Title {get; set; }
    }
```

How to join all Title with "-" in a `List<Title>` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this should give you what you're looking for. This will select the Title property from each object into a string array, and then join all elements of that array into a '-' separated string.

```
List<Title> lst = new List<Title>
                    { 
                        new Title{Id = 1, Title = "title1"}, 
                        new Title{Id = 2, Title = "title2"} 
                    }
String.Join("-", lst.Select(x => x.Title).ToArray());
```

If you're using .NET 4.0 or later, there is now an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) to `String.Join` that will allow you to omit the `.ToArray()`:

```
String.Join("-", lst.Select(x => x.Title));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list.Select(x => x.Title).Aggregate((current, next) => current + "-" + next);
```

should return a string of them all chained by a -

Comment: Compilation Error: Cannot convert type string to Title

Comment: Ah, If you need to set it back as a list of titles theprise has teh solution you want.